# indexof searching for more value

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

I want to look at a box's text, and if it matches of a value stored in an ARRAY, then I would like to do something with it.

```
var ARRAY1 = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];   
if (select[i].innerHTML.indexOf('ARRAY1') != -1){//code here}
```

So as you see, I want the indexOf to give true if one of the array value is matched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to have something like

```
var ARRAY1 = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"],
    compareFunction = function(e) { return select[i].innerHTML.indexOf(e) !== -1; };   

if (ARRAY1.filter(compareFunction).length) {//code here}
```

Here `compareFunction` is a function which is called on every array item against your selected item's html. After it goes through all items in array it will return only matches, so the length will be positive in case matches are found. You may also be interested in using `some` instead of `filter` - depends on what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Simply switch the ARRAY1 with select[i].innerHTML

```
var ARRAY1 = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];   
if (ARRAY1.indexOf(select[i].innerHTML) != -1){//code here}
```

Also you could visit these tutorials for js.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp

Prototype.includes(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: Why use w3schools at all when you already know MDN? w3schools is still a poor reference

Comment: I need the opposite. I have an array with words and I have the div on the site with one word. If this word is on the list (in the array) then I want to do something

Comment: On that case, use:  for(var j in ARRAY1){ if(select[i].innerHTML.indexOf(ARRAY1[j]){//code here}) }